# Compare two columns of two excels and return 3rd column

Tags: excel

I want to compare two columns of two different Excel sheets and return the corresponding 3rd column value of 2nd excel sheet infront of corresponding matched rows of 1st excel sheet.

Suppose Excel 1 contains follow value

```
Sl.No   Count
-------------------------------
105       1  
106       2  
107       3  
108       4  
109       5  
110       6
```

Excel 2 contain

```
Sl.No   Count   Grade
-----------------------
108       4       A  
109       5       B  
110       6       C  
111       1       D
```

Expected result

```
Sl.No   Count   Grade
-------------------------
105       1  
106       2 
107       3 
108       4       A  
109       5       B  
110       6       C
```

Please suggest, what function should I use.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2,'Excel 2'!$A$2:$B$1000,2,FALSE)=B2,VLOOKUP(A2,'Excel 2'!$A$2:$C$1000,3, FALSE),""),"")
```

Put it into Cell C2 in your first sheet and fill down.

Comment: Hi Bzimoir,                                                                                              Thank you for your quick response, could you please explain a little this function as I am trying to get the outcome with this formula, do not see any  result.

Comment: Here is my example workbook, check it:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1SUd1Zjg1WkFwTVU

Answer (score 0):

Another formula option is below. A bit cleaner, but it's an array formula, so processing may be slower with large data sets.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A1&B1,Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B,0)),"")
```

It's an array formula, so be sure to press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` when exiting edit mode. If done right, excel will wrap curly brackets around the formula.

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for your quick response. i tried with the above formula you mentioned, didn't get the expected result, could you please explain a little.

Comment: @AkshayKumar - basically, it matches column A and B from sheet1 against column A and B from sheet 2 and returns corresponding value in column C from sheet 2 where sheet2 column A and B match sheet1 column A and B (all for each individual row in sheet1).